# Adobe Analytics- Scroll depth tracking

Tags: scroll, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

In Adobe Analytics is there a way to capture the 'Time spent' before the user scrolls?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [Time prior to event](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/analytics/components/dimensions/time-prior-to-event.html?lang=en#populate-this-dimension-with-data).

If you send an event as a link beacon when the user starts scrolling—e.g. using Adobe Launch—the Time prior to event dimension will tell you how much time has passd before the user scrolled.

This seems to only work on the site-level, not page-level. If you need numbers for a specific page, perhaps you can create a segment that only includes hits on that particular page. That might give you the time-to-scroll on the specific page.